# EC2 instance allows me and connection closes after the login

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have been trying to log in to EC2 instance. Until my last session everything worked fine. But now when i try to login using the ssh, it shows **welcome to ubuntu** and  *Connection to xxxx.com closed.*

I got the following after the connection is closed

```
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to xx.compute.amazonaws.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2876, received 4196 bytes, in 4.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 697.0, received 1016.9
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Is there someway I can fix this, Also am not able to access them using the AWS remote session as well.

Edit 1 - adding full ssh debugging

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/abhishek/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file AbhishekTest.pem type -1
debug1: identity file AbhishekTest.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/abhishek/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/abhishek/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xxxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:zgJBfhSG1OJaQv7OeLLZ5RVnfDORICavQN504jQmTr8
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/abhishek/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/abhishek/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xxxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/abhishek/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/abhishek/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx.xx.xx.xx
debug1: Host 'xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/abhishek/.ssh/known_hosts:30
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: AbhishekTest.pem  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: AbhishekTest.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:kBwEaWBOFN1I8y0vW62EetzdvnYNsT/bnUs9109XIoA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xxx.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com ([xx.xx.xx.xx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = 3.3.12
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env COLORFGBG
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_PROFILE
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL = iTerm2
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env ITERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env ZSH
debug3: Ignored env PAGER
debug3: Ignored env LESS
debug3: Ignored env LSCOLORS
debug3: Ignored env PERL5LIB
debug3: Ignored env PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT
debug3: Ignored env PERL_MB_OPT
debug3: Ignored env PERL_MM_OPT
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LDFLAGS
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_EXE
debug3: Ignored env _CE_M
debug3: Ignored env _CE_CONDA
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PYTHON_EXE
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env JAVA_HOME
debug3: Ignored env DERBY_HOME
debug3: Ignored env STARSHIP_SHELL
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.3.0-1032-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Wed Aug 12 10:44:36 UTC 2020

  System load:  0.07               Processes:           118
  Usage of /:   88.5% of 19.32GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 46%                IP address for eth0: xx.xx.xx.xx
  Swap usage:   0%

  => / is using 88.5% of 19.32GB

 * Are you ready for Kubernetes 1.19? It's nearly here! Try RC3 with
   sudo snap install microk8s --channel=1.19/candidate --classic

   https://microk8s.io/ has docs and details.

 * Canonical Livepatch is available for installation.
   - Reduce system reboots and improve kernel security. Activate at:
     https://ubuntu.com/livepatch

2 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


Last login: Wed Aug 12 10:44:24 2020 from xx.xx.xx.xx
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 7 efd 8 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 6 efd 8 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
```

Comment: Does the instance screenshot show anything useful? (Right click > Instance Settings)

Comment: @Exelian Nope, its just the login screen. Nothing else

Comment: Is that full debugging? Can you use `ssh -vvv`? Please also show us your SSH command (but hide sensitive bits).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have added it now

Comment: Well, it did successfully connect, so you don't have a problem with the network or keypairs. It's just something on that instance that doesn't like you. Worst case, you can recover the data by detaching that disk volume and attaching it to another instance.